# How to Merge two json files into one in python3.6

Tags: json, python-3.6

Merge two json files into one in python3.6

I tried data1.update(data2),it didn't work

```
import json

with open("test.json") as fin1:
    data1 = json.load(fin1)
with open("test_userz.json") as fin2:
    data2 = json.load(fin2)

data1.update(data2)
with open("merged.json", "w") as fout:
    json.dump(data1, fout)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could merge like so

```
>>> data1=json.loads('{"test1":"one"}')
>>> data2=json.loads('{"test2":"two"}')
>>> data3=[]
>>> data3.append(data1)
>>> data3.append(data2)
>>> json.dumps(data3)
'[{"test1": "one"}, {"test2": "two"}]'
```